# $\frac{\cos^2(2x)}{5-2x} $ as $x \to\infty$, using squeeze theorem?

Tags: calculus, limits

any help would be appreciated, I got the solution to be 0 but I did not use the squeeze theorem, so I don't know how to show that.

$$\frac{\cos^2(2x)}{5-2x} $$

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
$$\frac{1}{5-2x} \leq \frac{\cos^2(2x)}{5-2x} \leq 0$$
For all $x > \frac52$